# Unix program to use barcode input and cURL command on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, unix, curl, raspberry-pi, barcode-scanner

I want to build a program that will run in unix (raspberry pi) that will simply wait for input from a barcode reader and add the input into a cURL command, and then execute that command.  The url is something like:

> http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=123456789

where `123456789` would be the input.

Typically when a barcode is read with a scanner, it will add in a carriage return after it reads the code, meaning if you scanned it into a text editor, you would see the barcode and the cursor would be on the next line.  I apologize for my ineptitude of programming - it's my parents fault ;)

I intend on running this program on startup of the Raspberry Pi instead of it running the desktop gui program, so some insight on that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your barcode reader sends the characters via keyboard input and does indeed put a CR after the barcode, I should think something like this would work.  Compile w/gcc:

gcc -o runcurl runcurl.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])

    {
    while (1)
        {
        char buf[256],syscmd[512];
        int i;

        /* Get next barcode */
        printf("Waiting for bar code [q=quit]:  ");
        if (fgets(buf,255,stdin)==NULL)
            break;

        /* Clean CR/LF off of string */
        for (i=0;buf[i]!='\0' && buf[i]!='\r' && buf[i]!='\n';i++);
        buf[i]='\0';

        /* q = quit */
        if (!strcmp(buf,"q"))
            break;

        /* Build into curl command */
        sprintf(syscmd,"curl \"http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=%s\"",buf);

        /* Execute--this will wait for command to complete before continuing. */
        system(syscmd);
        }
    return(0);
    }
```